# gwt flowpanel automatically show the bottm of the panel not the top

Tags: gwt

I have couple FlowPanels related like pages in a book, when i click the 'next' button it will go to the next page, which is flowPanel too. on one of the page, it have lots of widgets, from previous page to this page, it always goes to the bottom of the page not the top. how can i make it show the top of the page instead?  thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean scrolling to the top of the browser window, take a look at [Window.scrollTo()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)